# Registration of implementation for IEnumerables only using type parameters

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I'm trying to figure out the syntax to register a particular implementation of an interface and I just can't suss it out (using Simple Injector).  My interface signature looks like this:

```
public interface IAdditionalDataService<TResult, TModel>
```

I would like to register an implementation for whenever the first type parameter is an IEnumerable of type TModel, for example:

```
public class CompositeAdditionalDataService<TModel>
                 : IAdditionalDataService<IEnumerable<TModel>, TModel>
```

How would I do this?

I've tried this:

```
container.RegisterOpenGeneric(typeof(IAdditionalDataService<,>),
    typeof(CompositeAdditionalDataService<>));
```

And I get an error when I verify the container saying that there is no registration for `IAdditionalDataService<List<User>, User>`, so my registration has not worked.

I've also tried this:

```
container.RegisterOpenGeneric(typeof(IAdditionalDataService<IEnumerable<>,>),
    typeof(CompositeAdditionalDataService<>));
```

But this doesn't even compile, obviously, because it's not valid syntax.

**So my question is**

How can I register my implementation so it is used whenever a IAdditionalDataService, TModel> is requested, where TModel is a type parameter, so it could be almost anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your generic implementation to the following:

```
public class CompositeAdditionalDataService<TCollectionResult, TModel>
    : IAdditionalDataService<TCollectionResult, TModel>
    where TCollectionResult : IEnumerable<TModel>
```

and register it as follows:

```
// Simple Injector v3.x
container.Register(
    typeof(IAdditionalDataService<,>),
    typeof(CompositeAdditionalDataService<,>));

// Simple Injector v2.x
container.RegisterOpenGeneric(
    typeof(IAdditionalDataService<,>),
    typeof(CompositeAdditionalDataService<,>));
```